# Let $ f: (a, b) \to\mathbb R $ a function of class $ C^{\infty} $ that satisfies the following condition: given $ K \subset (a, b) $ compact...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

> Let $ f: (a, b) \to\mathbb R $ a function of class $ C^{\infty} $ that satisfies the following condition: given $ K \subset (a, b) $ compact, there exists $ C \gt 0 $ such that $ f^{(n)} (x) \le C^{n + 1} n! $, $ \forall n \in \mathbb Z_+ $, $ x \in K $. Prove that $ f $  is an analytical function.

In my notes we have the following.

Def: Let $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ open range of $f \in C^{\infty}(I)$. We say $f$ is analytic on $I$,if given $\exists r \gt 0$

such that $(a-r, a+r) \subseteq I$
$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}a}{n!}(x-a)^n \forall x\in (a-r, a+r )$

Prop:Let $f \in C^{\infty}(I) (I$ open) suppose that $\exists M \gt 0$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)| \le M$, $\forall n \in \mathbb Z_+, x\in I$. So $f$ is analytic on $I$.

From the prop and knowing that $C \gt 0$ and $n$ is positive don't we already have that $f$ is analytic? Are the Def and Prop correct?  Or did I get something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In the proposition $M$ has to be independent of $n$.

Comment: You have to use Taylor formula  for the remainder and then, based on estimates on $n+1$ derivative show that the tail tends to zero (if $x$ is sufficiently close to the point around which one develops Taylor series i.e $|x-a| < 1/C$. For the background check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem